# Does ServiceBase.Run(ServiceBase[] ) method run all services in array asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

```
ServiceBase[] servicesToRun;
            servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Service1(),
                new Service2()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
```

How will this work? Will Service1 be run, and when its `OnStart()` is done, Service2's `OnStart()` will be run, or both of them will run at the same time?
If that's the case, and I explicitly want Service1's `OnStart` to be done before running `Service2.OnStart()`, how would I go?

Would this do the trick:

```
ServiceBase.Run(new Service1())
ServiceBase.Run(new Service2())
```

Comment: it will run `Service1` first, as array is index based so

Comment: you always have option to delete question

Comment: I don't think you should *assume* anything about startup ordering. If Service 2 shouldn't start until Service 1 has, this should be modelled explicitly as a dependency.

Comment: This just promises an *initialization* order, it is inconsequential.  OnStart() is called, later, by the service manager.  The order is not predictable.  And can be completely random when a human starts/stops the services by hand.  You have to interlock this yourself.  Unless Service2 has a reason for being by itself, you should just make this a single service.

Comment: Calling ServiceBase.Run causes that method to call ServiceCtrlDispatcher for each service specified.  This results in the service control manager starting a process and/or thread for your service main function.  It will definitely do them in the order you specified, but there is nothing to say that service1 will have completed its initialization before service2 starts (indeed, this is likely to occur).    If you have this dependency, you need to configure service2 to have a dependency on service1.  You can do this with other configuration classes provided by the framework.

Comment: @JeffPrince: I think it's wrong to say that it will do them in order.  For one thing, if only one service has been started, the other service main function won't be called at all!

Comment: @Harry: I just meant if you specified two, the code in ServiceBase.Run runs a for loop on those two items and calls ServiceCtrlDispatcher on each.  Obviously, what the services then do in their initialization is unpredictable.  Establishing dependency of one on the other is strictly a matter of configuration and shouldn't be based on assumptions about what the services will do in OnStart();

Comment: @JeffPrince: I believe it only calls StartServiceCtrlDispatcher once, since once is all you get.  (The call never returns, IIRC.)  I don't see any guarantee in the documentation that the service main functions (aka OnStart) will be called in any particular order, and obviously they won't be called at all for services that aren't being started.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, I completely misread that code.  It calls StartServiceCtrlDispatcher with all the services requested.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I was this many days old when I learned I can package multiple services into a single exe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what `ServiceBase.Run()` actually does.

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6esb073b(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Registers the executable for multiple services with the Service Control Manager (SCM).

The sequence goes like this:

- A start request is received for one (or perhaps both) services.
- The SCM launches the executable.
- Your main function calls ServiceBase.Run().
- The SCM calls OnStart() for the service matching the start request, in a new thread.  *Unless both services are being started, OnStart() will **not** be called for the other one!*

If both services *are* being started then the order in which OnStart() is called is indeterminate, unless one service has been configured to have a dependency on the other.  Configuring such a dependency is the only safe way to ensure a particular ordering, any trickery such as waiting in one OnStart() for a signal from the other one may cause the SCM to deadlock.

If only one service was started, and later on the other service is started, the SCM will call the OnStart() for the second service at that point.

The call to ServiceBase.Run() will not return until the service reports that it is stopped.  If you have registered more than one service, it will not return until all the services are stopped.  At that point your process is expected to exit.

---

Note that your second code segment is definitely wrong.  The first call won't return until Service1 has been stopped, at which point the second call is illegal and will probably fail - at any rate, it certainly won't do anything useful.

Also note that if the two services cannot run independently of one another, there is probably no point in having two services in the first place.  The only case I could think of where it would be sensible is if you want the user to be able to stop and start Service2 while leaving Service1 running.

Comment: While testing I found something interesting.
ServiceBase.Run() does not return unless start fails or until the service is stopped. So additional code lines to start other services will not even be hit until one of these happens. And those other services will likely be started and then immediately stopped.

Comment: @pwrgreg007, yes, under the hood the call to ServiceBase.Run() calls StartServiceCtrlDispatcher which implements a dispatcher for the SCM.  That's how the SCM communicates with your process so it has to continue running until the point at which the SCM is ready for your process to exit.  I've rewritten the relevant part of my answer so as to make this clearer.